# Get midpoint of SDO.GEOMETRY polyline

Tags: oracle, geometry, coordinates, centroid, oracle-spatial

I have a table in Oracle 18c that has an SDO_GEOMETRY column with polylines.

I want to query the X and Y coordinates of the polyline midpoints using SQL.

Is there a way to do this with Oracle Spatial?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have Oracle Spatial?  It's installed by default, and as of a few days ago it's now [free for all editions](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/spatial-now-free-with-all-editions-of-oracle-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Spatial has a [linear referencing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_lrs_concepts.htm#SPATL060) package called  [SDO_LRS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_lrs_ref.htm#SPATL150). It can be used to find the midpoint coordinates of a polyline.

```
--In this case, 'sdo' is the name of the sdo_geometry column.

sdo_lrs.convert_to_std_geom(sdo_lrs.locate_pt(sdo_lrs.convert_to_lrs_geom(sdo,3)
    ,sdo_geom.sdo_length(sdo,3)/2)).sdo_point.x as midpoint_x,

sdo_lrs.convert_to_std_geom(sdo_lrs.locate_pt(sdo_lrs.convert_to_lrs_geom(sdo,3)
    ,sdo_geom.sdo_length(sdo,3)/2)).sdo_point.y as midpoint_y
```

---

For bonus points:

This is how ESRI's [SDE.ST_GEOMETRY](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) can be converted to SDO_GEOMETRY for the purpose of getting the midpoint coordinates:

```
select
    sdo_lrs.convert_to_std_geom(sdo_lrs.locate_pt(sdo_lrs.convert_to_lrs_geom(sdo,3),sdo_geom.sdo_length(sdo,3)/2)).sdo_point.x as midpoint_x,
    sdo_lrs.convert_to_std_geom(sdo_lrs.locate_pt(sdo_lrs.convert_to_lrs_geom(sdo,3),sdo_geom.sdo_length(sdo,3)/2)).sdo_point.y as midpoint_y
from
    (select
        sdo_util.from_wktgeometry(sde.st_astext(shape)) as sdo
    from
        roads)
```

---

*This answer was inspired by an answer on Code Review: [Calculate the midpoint of a polyline](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/234325/206844).*